# Find element in matrix and substitute

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have data.frame of survey results. The responses are in Portuguese language and I need to substitute some responses, for instance, "Não sabe" and "Não respondeu" by "Ns/Nr". Each column of the matrix is of factor class.
Can I generalize this procedure for any labels?
I tried something like this

```
mydata[mydata %in% c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")] <- "Ns/Nr"
```

But, it doesn't work. In fact, when I tried:

```
mydata[mydata %in% c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")]<- "Ns/Nr"
```

there is not error, but, when I do

```
freq(mydata$Q_9)
```

there is no "Ns/Nr" label and the other frequencies remain the same. And, when I do

```
mydata[mydata == "Não respondeu"]<- "Ns/Nr"
```

there are warnings like

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "Ns/Nr") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

In this case, when I do freq(mydata$Q_9), the frequence of the "Não respondeu" is zero and NA takes the frequence of the old "Não respondeu".

Comment: Sorry, "Ns/Nr" is the correct. In fact, I have iquals warnings like this  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "Ns/Nr") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: In fact, when i tried: mydata[mydata %in% c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")]<- "Ns/Nr" there is not error, but when I do freq(mydata$Q_9) there is no "Ns/Nr' label and the other frequencies remain the same. When I do mydata[mydata == "Não respondeu"]<- "Ns/Nr" there are warnings

Comment: I think you need to change the 'factor' class to 'character' class. i.e `mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, as.character)` before the assigment or. change the factor columns to have the levels `"Ns/Nr"`.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example as I didn't test your case

Comment: Also, the `%in%` wouldn't work as you expected if you have a data.frame.  Though, you mentioned it as matrix, I doubt it because of the warning you got.  Matrix don't have factor class

Comment: Try `mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) {x[ x %in%c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")] <- 'Ns/Nr'; x})` after converting to character class

Comment: It really works.. What is the diference between your suggestion and mydata[mydata %in% c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")]<- "Ns/Nr" ?

Comment: As I mentioned, your dataset seems to be a data.frame.  So, the `%in%` result will be a single element for each column.  You can check it by `mydata %in% c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")`

Comment: Sorry, the matrix, in fact, is a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the 'factor' class to 'character' before substituting i.e.

```
 mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, as.character)
 mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) {
        x[ x %in%c("Não sabe", "Não respondeu")] <- 'Ns/Nr'
         x})
```

Or without converting to 'character' class we can use `recode` from `car`.  The advantage is that you can have new levels 'Ns/Nr' updated in the 'factor' column while dropping the levels replaced.

```
 library(car)
 mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) 
         recode(x, "c('Não sabe', 'Não respondeu')='Ns/Nr'") )
```

Comment: If I avoid convert, it would be better. But in this case, the following error appears: Error in recode(x, "c('Não sabe', 'Não respondeu')='Ns/Nr'") : 
  invalid recoding request

Comment: Other information: my data.frame has some numeric columns, but in this columns ther is not "Não sabe", "Não respondeu".. I think it is the problem... but, it is OK

Comment: I have a pertinent question, in terms of lapply functions, How can I convert only the columns which class is factor?

Comment: I tried somthig like this: classe<- lapply(mydata, class) and 
ind<- which(classe == "factor")... but, I don't know how to introduce ind in mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, as.character)

Comment: Resolved... mydata[,ind][] <- lapply(mydata[,ind], as.character)

Comment: @Vasco If you have numeric and other class. `ind <- sapply(mydata, is. factor); mydata[ind] <- lapply(mydata[ind], as.character)`  Regardig the `recode` issue, it must be the same problem.  You have to subset the columns that needs to be recoded.